# InputStream stream = new URL(params[0]).openStream();

Tags: java, android, geolocalización

Necesito enviar por get una variable adicional a la url , mi codigo es este

```
private final String mGeoJsonUrl = "http://181.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/MIPAGINA.php?id=" + id ;

protected void start() {
    DownloadGeoJsonFile downloadGeoJsonFile = new DownloadGeoJsonFile();
    // Download the GeoJSON file
    downloadGeoJsonFile.execute(mGeoJsonUrl);
}

protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
           // List params = new ArrayList();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            // Open a stream from the URL
            InputStream stream = new URL(params[0]).openStream();
           // JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(mGeoJsonUrl, "GET", params);

            String line;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Read and save each line of the stream
                result.append(line);
            }
            // Close the stream
            reader.close();
            stream.close();
            // Convert result to JSONObject
            return new JSONObject(result.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(mLogTag, "GeoJSON file could not be read");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(mLogTag, "GeoJSON file could not be converted to a JSONObject");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Con ese código tienes algún problema, error o podrías ser un poco mas especifico en lo que necesitas?

Comment: hola el codigo lo que devuelve es un Geojson para mostrar unos marcadores en un mapa pero necesito enviar una variable de sesion (nombre de usuario) pero me marca error al enviar la url

Comment: podrías incluir en tu pregunta el error que obtienes?

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas enviar un parametro adicional en un `GET` Request simplemente agregala en el url, por ejemplo si deseas enviar el valor de la variable `titulo`, esta seria la forma

```
String miTitulo = "StackOverflow";

private final String mGeoJsonUrl = "http://181.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/MIPAGINA.php?id=" + id + "&titulo=" + miTitulo;
```

Recuerda que la primera variable se agrega a el url con **`?`** y las siguientes se concatenan con **`&`**.